# Clear image rendered using drawInRect

Tags: ios, drawrect

I have a setup where I need to render 3 images and blend them. I use this in drawRect

```
[self.backImage.image drawInRect:self.backImage.frame blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
```

I do some transforms on the UIImageView and then call setNeedsDisplay which flags the Parent view to trigger drawRect. When drawRect fires again it seems to render the images again without the old images being removed.

I set `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` on the parent and on the image views but it does not seem to fix the issue.

How can I clear the old images before the next ones are cleared? It is almost like once the images are rendered using drawInRect they are forgotten about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried drawing over with `kCGBlendModeClear`? This should enable you to clear things out before you draw the new one.

Alternately, you could try to do your drawing to an off-screen bitmap context. Then in your `drawRect`, copy from this off-screen buffer to the view. This may successfully draw over the old image.

**Edit:** Essentially you would use `kCGBlendModeClear` as an eraser before drawing your new content.

Comment: Thanks. I will try kCGBlendModeClear.